# Sending auto email after uploading of files?

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

There are two files which get uploded in D:\CW-Data\edw location every day between 1am to 1:15 am.
My requirement is to auto send us the email wih the file name when both the files are received.
I tried writing a cript which troughs the lastfile which arrives, but i am not getting the expected result. Please help me out:
My script was

```
set srcDir=D:\Mitul\Quantum AWR Report_23Apr_3am_2pm
set lastmod=
pushd %srcDir%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od 2^>NUL') do set lastmod=%%a
echo %lastmod%
```

Comment: What are the expected and the actual results?

Comment: @peter i need the complete script for sending the mail. Please ignore the script that i have mentoned.It just throughs up the last modified file .

Comment: All I did was reformat the script you posted. Like anyone else, I have no idea of what your expectations are - you have to specify what you want. What is your "expected result?" What result did you get? What result are you aiming for?

Comment: @peter   i need the two file names that do export into my dir,every day. and i should get a email when both files are arrived in the dir.

Comment: `a cript which troughs`  ?

Comment: "A script which throws up the filename" is how I interpreted it.

Comment: @PeterWright , sir, i need a help, the following script that i have written througs only the file name, i need the file size too of those files, plese help me out:@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set srcDir=D:\Pradeep\GC ITO Roaster
pushd %srcDir%
set /a count_=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od 2^>NUL') do (
set /a count_+=1
set my_arr[!count_!]=%%a
)

type nul>D:\Pradeep\output.log
set /a mm=%count_%-2


for /l %%N in (1 1 %count_%) do (
if %%N GTR %mm% (
echo !my_arr[%%N]! >> D:\Pradeep\output.log

)
)

Answer (score 1):

This is a general purpose script for sending an email.

Original thread at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/alt.msdos.batch.nt/l_8K11YzS0A/WfbVBoJe-l8J

```
:: Allows ssl and port 465



:: email.cmd ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Tom Lavedas, Mod 2.14 to eliminate temporary VBS script file
:: Works with IE5+ (and maybe earlier versions as well)
 @echo off
  setlocal

 :Use command line arguments, if supplied
  if [%1] EQU [] goto :Continue
    set "Arg=%1"
    set "Arg=%Arg::==%"
    set "Arg=%Arg:/=%"
    set "%Arg%"
    shift
    goto :Use 
 :Continue

:: defaults 
  if not defined From       set "From=userid@gmail.com"
  if not defined To         set "To=you@somemail.com"
  if not defined Subj       set Subj="email test   %date% %time%"
  if not defined Body       set Body="Did it work? %date% %time%"
  if not defined Serv       set "Serv=smtp.gmail.com"
  if not defined Auth       set "Auth=userid@gmail.com"
  if not defined Pass       set "Pass=password"
  if not defined fileattach set "fileattach="
  if not defined Port       set "Port=465"
  if not defined SSL        set "SSL=True"
  if not defined Timeout    set "Timeout=25"

  call :send %From% %To% %Subj% %Body% %Serv% %Auth% %Pass% %fileattach%
  if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 echo Error: %ErrorLevel%
  if %0==%~f0 pause
  exit /b %ErrorLevel%

 :send

  set "cdoSchema=http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration"
  set arguments="%~1+%~2+%~3+%~4+%~5+%~6+%~7+%~f8"

  set VBS=resizeTo 1,1:moveTo 1, 3000:
  set VBS=%VBS%set ws=createobject("wscript.shell"):
  set VBS=%VBS%with createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  set VBS=%VBS%Execute ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(
  set VBS=%VBS%.GetStandardStream(0).readALL):end with:
  set "VBS=about:<script type=text/vbs>%VBS%:close</script>"

  set "Match=VBScript start"
  for /f "delims=[]" %%N in (
    'find /n "### %Match% ###" ^<"%~f0"'
  ) do set "N=%%N"

  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%A in (
    'more +%N% "%~f0" ^| mshta.exe "%VBS%"'
  ) do @echo %%B & exit /b %%A
  exit /b 1 % Error in previous statement %

' ### VBScript start ###
 set StdOut=.GetStandardStream(1)
 args = Split(%arguments%, "+")
 with CreateObject("CDO.Message")
   .From     = args(0)
   .To       = args(1)
   .Subject  = args(2)
   .Textbody = args(3)
  if args(7) <> "" then .AddAttachment args(7)
   with .Configuration.Fields
     .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendusing")        = 2 ' not local, smtp
     .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpserver")       = args(4)
     .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpserverport")   = %Port%
     .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpauthenticate") = 1 ' cdobasic
     .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendusername")     = args(5)
     .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendpassword")     = args(6)
     .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpusessl")       = %SSL%
     .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpconnectiontimeout") = %Timeout%
     .Update 
   end with ' Configuration.Fields
   On Error Resume Next
   .Send
 end with ' CDO.Message
 if Err.Number = 0 then
   sRes = "0#Mail sent without error"
 else
   sRes = Hex(Err.Number) + "#" + Err.Description
 end if
 stdout.writeline sRes
' ### VBScript end ### - Must be the end of the batch file
```

Comment: @foxdrive  i cannot configure gmail to it as its a client environment. and could you please update me with the script so thet i could get a out put as i require.

Comment: It works with any email server.  Sorry that the comment was a little confusing.  You can use your script and then call this script, after you configure the server etc, or use call and add everything from the command line.

Comment: hi all,i have one more small cocerns, please find the output of my script, i want the file size of the files too, please help me out:@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set srcDir=D:\Pradeep\GC ITO Roaster
pushd %srcDir%
set /a count_=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od 2^>NUL') do (
set /a count_+=1
set my_arr[!count_!]=%%a
)

type nul>D:\Pradeep\output.log
set /a mm=%count_%-2


for /l %%N in (1 1 %count_%) do (
if %%N GTR %mm% (
echo !my_arr[%%N]! >> D:\Pradeep\output.log

)
)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set srcDir=D:\CW-Data\edw
set file1=whateverthenameofthefirstfileis
set file2=whateverthenameofthesecondfileis
:loop
set /a count=0
for /f %%a in ('dir /b "%srcdir%\%file1%" "%srcdir%\%file2%" 2^>NUL') do set /a count+=1
IF NOT %count%==2 timeout /t 5 >nul&GOTO loop 
echo send the email
```

This will wait for the two files to arrive. If either is missing, timeout 5 seconds and try again.

Don't have enough details to provide more.

---

Addendum:

If your edition of windows doesn't include `timeout`, try

```
IF NOT %count%==2 ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 >nul&GOTO loop
```

Comment: please let me know how to configure this output to mail.should i install smtp to my server?

Comment: Or [bmail](http://retired.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm).

Comment: @peter while executing it i am geting a error as 'timeout is not a reconised commond.' please help

Comment: i have found out the out put. thanks to all..                                                                                                     @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set srcDir=D:\Pradeep\GC ITO Roaster
pushd %srcDir%
set /a count_=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od  2^>NUL') do (
set /a count_+=1
set my_arr[!count_!]=%%a
)

type nul>D:\Pradeep\output.log
set /a mm=%count_%-2

for /l %%N in (1 1 %count_%) do (
if %%N GTR %mm% (
echo !my_arr[%%N]! >> D:\Pradeep\output.log
)
)

Comment: @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set srcDir=D:\Pradeep\GC ITO Roaster
pushd %srcDir%
set /a count_=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od 2^>NUL') do (
set /a count_+=1
set my_arr[!count_!]=%%a
)

type nul>D:\Pradeep\output.log
set /a mm=%count_%-2


for /l %%N in (1 1 %count_%) do (
if %%N GTR %mm% (
echo !my_arr[%%N]! >> D:\Pradeep\output.log

)
)